# How to group data to specific ranges and mutate vectors in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am trying to organize and mutate my data in R.

Essentially I am trying to graph the average of B, for data ranges in A

Original Data Set

```
      A          B
    <dbl>     <dbl>
1    200       28  
2   1053      67.3
3  17000.      30  
4   7565.      12  
5  14525       56  
6   3411       30
```

What I am trying to transform my data into

```
    Ranges            Average 
   0 - 999.99            23%
1000 - 1999.99           45%
2000 - 2999.99           32%  
3000 - 3999.99           50%
```

This is what I have so far for this function

```
A1 <- read_excel("file")
DataRange <- data.frame( A= A1$C, 
                         B= A1$R)


# Function 1
ranges1 <- DataRange %>% mutate(new_range=cut(A, breaks = seq(min(A),max(A)), by = 999))
```

The Output of range1 is

```
232    699.00   23.00000     (699,700]
233    445.00   33.00000     (445,446]
234   3112.00   28.00000   (3112,3113]
235   1235.00   98.00000   (1235,1236]
```

This is a breakdown from the function I am working with

```
# Function 2
ranges1 <- DataRange %>% mutate(new_range=cut(A, breaks = seq(min(A),max(A)), by = 999)
                               %>% group_by(new_range)
                               %>% dplyr::summarize(mean_1 = mean(B))
                               %>% as.data.frame())
```

The output of range1 is:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `new_range = ... %>% as.data.frame()`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "factor"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

As you can tell I am jumping the gun on the first problem, but the later function is where I am trying to take this expression.

I am really confused about how to fix the first function, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error. You need to have the `%>%` pipes at the ends of lines, not the start of lines. When your line ends after the `mutate()` R thinks that command is complete. Then the next line starts with `%>%` and the data didn't actually get piped through.

Change it to this:

```
ranges1 <- DataRange %>% 
  mutate(new_range=cut(A, breaks = seq(min(A),max(A)), by = 999)) %>%
  group_by(new_range) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(mean_1 = mean(B)) %>%
  as.data.frame())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, I am still getting the whole `Error in `mutate()`:` error

Comment: I even tried it on a smaller data set to debug it even further, still running into the same error.

Comment: Just noticed you were also missing a `)` to end the `mutate()`. Added that to my answer, I think it should work now.